# Stack around the variable 'equation' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-leaks, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator in VC++ and even though it runs, it keeps reading memory that I haven't told it to, and I don't know how to make it stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

char equation[4];
equation[3] = '\0'; //string terminator
int result;
bool wantsToContinue = true;
char yesOrNo;

equationPrompt:
std::cout << "Enter Equation: ";
std::cin >> equation;

while(wantsToContinue){

    switch(equation[1]){
    case '+':
        result = int(equation[0]) + int(equation[2]);
        break;
    case '-':
        result = int(equation[0]) - int(equation[2]);
        break;
    case '*':
        result = int(equation[0]) * int(equation[2]);
        break;
    case '/':
        result = int(equation[0]) / int(equation[2]);
        break;
    }

std::cout << std::endl << "Your answer is " << result << std::endl;
exitPrompt:
std::cout << "Exit? Y/N: ";
std::cin >> yesOrNo;

if(tolower(yesOrNo) == 'n'){
    wantsToContinue = true;
    goto equationPrompt;
}
else if (tolower(yesOrNo) == 'y')
    wantsToContinue = false;
else{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Unknown response." << std::endl;
    goto exitPrompt;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) The `>>` operator for `cin` has *no way* to tell how large a buffer it is reading into. 2) Get rid of the `goto` statements by using `continue` and `break` as needed. 3) You need a `default:` case for your `switch`. 4) Use `std:cerr` for error messages.

Comment: goto is usually considered bad.  You should be able to do without it with only minor changes.

Comment: The memory error is probably caused by when you type in numbers greater than 9 or less than 0.  If you type those in, this will write past the end of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make it stop by not writing an arcane Frankenstein language mix of C and C++, but instead using real C++ string types:

```
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
  std::string equation;
  std::cin >> equation;

  // now equation[0] is the first character
}
```

Note that `int(equation[0])` is almost guaranteed not to be what you think. What you want is something like `int x = std::atoi(equation[0]);` or `std::strtol()`, but that only works for single digits. Probably much simpler to just stream into an integer, which performs an actual text-to-integer conversion:

```
int x, y;
std::string operand;

std::cin >> x >> operand >> y;
```

Comment: Thanks so much; i should have used the atoi() method and a string.

Comment: Yeah, but you also really shouldn't be reading into a `char[4]`!

Comment: Why do people call arrays "an arcane Frankenstein language mix of C and C++" when "real C++ strings" are just wrappers around arrays written by some programmer and put into a library? arrays are just as "real C++" as classes are. And when you're starting out, you should use arrays so you know how strings work underneath and you have enough knowledge to write your own string class.

Comment: @Seth: `cin >> x` is fine when `x` is a string, but can kill you if it is a raw array. Isn't that a good enough reason? **Especially** in the OP's context where there's absolutely no reason why the user should only input one-digit numbers.

Comment: Being able to kill you doesn't make it not C++ any more.

Comment: @Seth: also an `if` is "just a wrapper around a `cmp` and a conditional `jmp` written by some programmer and put into a compiler". Still, if you wrote inline assembly instead of just `if` your code could be easily considered "an arcane Frankenstein language mix of C and assembly". Sometimes dealing with low level details is needed, but much more often it's better to leave them to others (e.g. library/compiler writers).

Comment: I think Herb Sutter said it very nicely once; C++ is a language for library writers. The idiomatic C++ approach to life is to write a library for your problem and then use it. `std::string` exemplifies this philosophy perfectly. Yes, C++ has access to lower-level features, but using those is no more C++ than hitting a piano key is a symphony.

Comment: @Matteo: Someone on SO once put this very nicely when someone mentioned that you can write classes with just functions: "Yes, and you can also replace loops with gotos and functions with copy-paste." True!

Comment: @Matteo I'm just advocating knowing how things work. It's good to know that an `if` is just a `cmp` and `jmp`. However, `if` is one of the basic building blocks of the language, but `string` is not. I can't write my own `if` using only the language's features, but I _can_ write my own `string` (an exercise everyone should do at one time or another by the way).

Comment: @Seth: obviously I was exaggerating, and we both know it `:)`. But the key point, here, is that C++ offers you the tools to avoid the C features that often give headaches, abstracting their complications away and making programming much easier and less error-prone. C strings and raw arrays often make you mix the logic of your code with the memory management associated with them, and this is a real source of confusion and errors for beginners. IMHO they should be presented immediately the "basic abstract tools" (e.g. `std::string`), explaining then how to build them on "raw C++" features.

Comment: @Matteo I know what you mean. I disagree though (which is fine) because if you give people the easy stuff first they become too dependent on what other people have done and can't do anything for themselves, and that just makes it difficult for them to learn what's really going on down the road. It's also good for people to know _why_ they're using strings, which they learn by having to do all the hard work of using more basic features. I've always thought  it's good to teach people longhand division before giving a calculator. But the whole point was that arrays aren't less C++ than strings.

Comment: @Seth: But we don't teach people how to do arithmetic in Roman numerals before we teach them fractions. I'd rather have someone ignorant of arrays write C++ code competently with strings than someone else write broken code with arrays thinking he can optimize some CPU cycles.

Comment: I'd rather have someone write C++ with strings and then _being able_ to correctly optimise with arrays _if needed_. That's the difference I guess. And roman numerals aren't the basis of fractions.

Answer (score 0):

`equation` is an array of 4 `char`s.

```
std::cin >> equation;
```

reads an arbitrarily long string into that array.  Type too much, and it will overflow, stepping on adjacent memory.

As @Kerrek SB says, you're better off using `std::string`, which doesn't have that problem.